# error writing in file vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a file using VBA. My code is below. It worked the first time, but when i closed the excel file (.xlsm) and try to use it again, it doesn't work.

I do not get any errors when running the macro but the new file does not appear

```
Sub LogInformation(LogMessage As String)
  Const LogFileName As String = "TEXTFILE.db"
  Dim FileNum As Integer
  FileNum = FreeFile ' next file number
  Open LogFileName For Append As #FileNum ' creates the file if it doesn't exist
  Print #FileNum, LogMessage ' write information at the end of the text file
  Close #FileNum ' close the file
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it because 'FileNum = FreeFile' always finds the 'Next' file number?

Comment: Ohh ok, I don't really know VBA much, sorry Ohh just realised, that it only creates a file when the file DOESN'T exist. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys. That was dumb. 
The default relative path is in User/%MyUser%/Documents.

I need to use ChDir then open/write/close the file.

```
  Chdir(ActiveWorkbook.Path)
```